# Изменение стоимости доставки в зависимости от выбранного периода доставки

Tags: php, битрикс

На [сайте](https://morecvetov.shop/) в качестве доставки используется модуль ["Расчет стоимости доставки по зонам с подсказками от DaData"](https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/corsik.yadelivery/?PAGEN_2=6#comments)
Возникла необходимость изменять стоимость доставки в зависимости от выбранного периода времени доставки и минимальная сумма заказа 990руб.
http://joxi.ru/v2983kRt4KyWJm

С 10:00 до 20:00 - доставка бесплатная

С 18:00 до 20:00 - доставка бесплатная

С 20:00 до 22:00 - стоимость доставки, как рассчитал модуль доставки

С 22:00 до 00:00 - стоимость доставки, как рассчитал модуль доставки

Т.е. при выборе того или иного значения доставка должна быть или бесплатной или платной. Отрабатывать должно на ajax.
В правилах работы с корзиной нет функциональности установки условия на свойства заказа.
Проблемы возникли с написанием обработчика, в котором должно отрабатывать событие. Судя по документации битрикса, должно срабатывать событие onSaleDeliveryServiceCalculate, но ничего не происходит. Может подскажете в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете сторонний модуль, то Вам нужно копать этот модуль. Раз не срабатывает стандартный onSaleDeliveryServiceCalculate, значит модуль его не дергает.

И тут единственный вариант - копаться в самом модуле. Или попробовать написать разработчику модуля свой вопрос. Тем более, что модуль платный и там должна быть поддержка.

Если функционал, который Вам нужен, не входит в функционал модуля, обычно разработчики за отдельную плату дорабатывают модули под нужды.